# Can the dispersion relation of a spin lattice be modified by entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, dispersion, spin-models

Suppose I have a cubic lattice of spins.
Suppose I can prepare these spins in an uncorrelated state. No spin correlations. No entanglement. No nothing.

Suppose I can measure the dispersion relation of my spin lattice using some Bragg spectroscopy technique, where I send two photons at a certain angle with a certain frequency difference. At the end of my experiment I get a typical dispersion curve E(q), where q is the wavevector of my excitation.

Is there any reason to believe that this dispersion relation should be modified by the emergence of entanglement between my spins?